# Visual Paradigm add two foreign key in a single table reference to single primary key?

Tags: sql, database, erd, visual-paradigm

Here we have many to many relationship between tour and places .

So Visual paradigm automatically add the bridge table but i want to keep Place Column two time as a foreign key in Tour_place table, 
Place_start (fk)
Place_destination (fk)  both referencing to the same column place for Place table.

I can easily create a table in  oracle sql with both of them as foreign key but i also need to show both as a foreign key in ERD.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be using a many-to-many relationship in the first place. A single tour has a single Start and End. Your design allows multiple.

Comment: no a same tour might contain many start and end as a tour may expand many days day 1 from here to there, day 2 another location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a another relationship association line
, now both Place_start and Place_destination reference the Pk places from Places table.

[image]